# Word for a boss who demands the best and also does the best himself

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for a boss/ leader who demands the best and also does the best themself.

**Examples:**

1. He asks the team to work late until 1am and he does it himself too.
2. He demands that every member of the team meets a ridiculous sales target and he meets it himself and surpasses all.
3. He asks his employees to come to work even if they're ill and it turns out he himself comes to work even though he's severely ill.

The word could be an adjective or a noun.

Comment: Do you take the approach to be a good one? If murder was still disallowed, I would quit and tell my friends I walked out on an a**hole.

Comment: Try *obsessive*, meaning "excessive in degree or nature" or "a person who is continually preoccupied with a particular activity, person, or thing."

Comment: I would say "demanding".

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but depending on your intent, this individual "leads by example" and acts as a "role model".

Even more idiomatically, the boss "practices what he preaches".

Comment: He also "sets a high bar".

Answer (score 1):

I would say such a person was [**exacting**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exacting):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : tryingly or unremittingly severe in making demands
> **2** : requiring careful attention and precision
>
> // He has very *exacting* standards.
> // he was shocked when his normally *exacting* supervisor complimented him on a job well done

Note the two senses of the word. The second sense is more task oriented, while the first has a kind of negative connotation to it. Both can apply at the same time. While the first sentence in the question suggests the second sense, the actual example sentences in the question suggest the first sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is one word that captures someone who works to extremes and expects their employees to follow that example.

A "workaholic" certainly describes a lot of what you put in the bullet points above, but it doesn't necessarily mean the boss would demand the same behavior others, just that the boss would do it themselves.

A masochistic, workaholic who demands the same of their employees.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of boss, I would say *he [leads by example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20by%20example) or he holds himself to his own high standards.*

You might want to use *[trailblazer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trailblazer)*.

A *trailblazer* is the first person to do something or go somewhere, who shows that it is also possible for other people.

*[Standard-bearer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/standard-bearer)* could also be used in some contexts.

*Standard-bearer* is the the person or thing that seems to lead a group of people having similar ideas or moral opinions.

*[Hard-ass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-ass)* is also used for such kind of demanding boss (though it's a vulgar word).

**(Obsessive–compulsive personality disorder (OCPD)** is a personality disorder characterized by excessive concern with orderliness, perfectionism, attention to details, mental and interpersonal control, and a need for control over one's environment, which interferes with flexibility, openness to experience, and efficiency, as well as interpersonal relationships. Workaholism and miserliness are also seen often in those with this personality disorder.)